# Haskell input multiple numbers -> output multiple numbers + divide

Tags: haskell

I want to get as an input 3 numbers and give as an output multiple results.

My code :

```
t :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer,Integer,Integer)
t a b c = ((a+b)/2,(a+b+c)/3,(b+c)/2)
```

But it seems to be a problem here:

```
Lab2.hs:17:17:
No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of `/'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
In the expression: (a + b) / 2
In the expression: ((a + b) / 2, (a + b + c) / 3, (b + c) / 2)
In an equation for `t':
    t a b c = ((a + b) / 2, (a + b + c) / 3, (b + c) / 2)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The problem is the multiple output OR the divide I try to do...

Answer (score 5):

`(/)` has the following type:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

`Integer` isn't an instance of `Fractional`. After all, it is possible that the result of dividing an integer an integer isn't an integer (e.g `3/2`).

You want to use `div`:

```
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

This works since `Integer` is an instance of `Integral` (check by using `:info Integer`). You can use infix notation to keep things clear:

```
(a + b) `div` 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zeta. The last line solved my problem. But just to understand better the div :: Integral a=> a -> a ->
How can I use the div :: or the :: Fractional inside a code to make it work? Thanks again for your answer. :)

Comment: You don't really 'use' the "div ::" or the ":: Fractional" inside the logic of your program. To put it simply, whenever you see something like NAME :: a -> b -> c, it means "The function called NAME, takes something of type 'a', then something of type 'b', and returns something of type 'c'", or more colloquially, NAME has type a -> b -> c. Now, when you add something like "Integral a =>" to the picture, it just means that "a doesn't have to be a specific type, but it must behave like an Integral (a whole number).

Comment: @STUDENT_LIFE: Actually, I don't quite get your comment question. Maybe you're talking about `t :: (Integral a) -> a -> a -> a -> (a, a, a)`?

Answer (score 3):

Following on to Zeta's answer (and your question in the comment), you could make your code return Doubles instead of Ints (thus covering the case where the divisor does not exactly go into the numerator).

For example:

```
t :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (Double, Double, Double)
t a b c = (fromIntegral (a+b) /2, fromIntegral (a+b+c)/3, fromIntegral (b+c)/2)
```

The conversion from Int to Double using fromIntegral (or generally from something that is not Fractional to something that is) is a common gotcha for people starting Haskell!

Notice how `fromIntegral`'s type is `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`, in that it takes something that is Integral (ie. a whole number like an int) and converts it to a fractional (like a Double).

It is not possible to do this via casting like in Java. The java code:

```
int x = 1;
foo((double) x);
```

would in Haskell be:

```
let x :: Int ; x = 1 in foo $ fromIntegral x
```